# Python For Loop Questinonnaire

Tags: python, for-loop

My code shall solve two problems:

1. What I want to do is to create a questionnaire, where people answer different questions on a scale from 1-5.
   The question structure remains so I tried a for a loop.

However, the output is always faulty... Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

#named the question subjects
factor_test_target_a1 = "name1"
factor_test_target_a2 = "name2"
factor_test_target_a3 = "name3"
factor_test_target_a4 = "name4"
factor_test_target_a5 = "name5"
factor_test_target_a6 = "name6"

#generated an array of question subjects to loop trough
test_target = pd.DataFrame([factor_test_target_a1, factor_test_target_a2, factor_test_target_a3, 
factor_test_target_a4, factor_test_target_a5,factor_test_target_a6])

#generated the for loop
for n in test_target: input("Please indicate the approriateness of" + str(n + 1) + "from 1-5: ")

print(n)
```

The error that comes is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

2. I aim to use the answer to n, in the following equation for a fixed variable for each subject meaning n= (ni- fixedfactori/ fixedfactori)

to do so I created the following equation:

```
reference = pd.DataFrame([4.3412, 4.327, 4.306, 4.200, 4.00, 3.775])

df_norm = test_target()
df_reference = reference()

#apply scaling
for n in test_target:
df_norm[n] = ((df_norm[str(n + 1)] - df_reference[str(n + 1)])/ df_reference[str(n + 1)])
print(n)
```

Here it gives me an error about the indent.

Comment: What is `n` in each of the code snippets? And what do you think will be the result of `n + 1`?

Comment: With n I wanted to refer to the factor e.g. n1 would be factor_test_target_a1. I guess in math it would be xi if test_target is X and x1=factor_test_target_a1;    The n+1 I read in a different post, was then intended to indicate the loop shall move in a structured way always computing the 0 positions with the 0 position, next the 1 position with the 1 position and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**the error is in the line
`str(n + 1)`**

here the value of n is from

[factor_test_target_a1, factor_test_target_a2, factor_test_target_a3,
factor_test_target_a4, factor_test_target_a5, factor_test_target_a6]

thus you can not add these strings with 1

```
for n in test_target: 
input("Please indicate the approriateness of" + str(n + 1) + "from 1-5: ")
```

I think you want to take the index of these elements use index property

Comment: Many thanks for your input :) In the meantime I found a different way to approach it! see below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
g=0
x = []
    for i in test_target:
        x.extend([float(input("Approriateness of the " + i + " on a scale of 1-5: "))])
        # print(x[g])
        g = g + 1
```

In that way I was able to loop through the process! Many thanks for the support.